# Why this line of code doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

Could someone please tell me why this line of code isn't working for me :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = (DataTable)this.dataGridView_Clients.DataSource;
```

I want to explicitly cast the DataSource object to DataTable but it is giving me this exception :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Volkswagen App.exe
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: What is the original type of the data source? If it is not a `DataTable`, you can't just cast it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `DataGridView` `DataSource` is of type `BindingSource` and not `DataTable` (in your case). You could try this :

```
dt = (DataTable)((BindingSource)this.dataGridView_Clients.DataSource).DataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because your `Datasource` is not a subtype of `DataTable` (nor a `DataTable`).